# Use generics as an argument and access methods of particular enums

Tags: java, generics, web-applications, enums

I am doing a web application and I have several `Enum` to set the values ​​of the dropdown of views (5 and counting ...)

The format of the Enums is the same:

```
public enum PetType {
    CAT ("Cat"),
    DOG ("Dog");

    private String type;

    PetType(String type) { this.type = type; }

    public void   setType(String type) { this.type = type; }
    public String getType()            { return this.type; }

}
```

I also use a DTO called `OptionDTO` to take these values ​​and bring them to view:

```
public class OptionDTO {
    private Integer value;
    private String option;

    / * Constructors, getters and setters * /

}
```

In the service I am creating an `OptionDTO` list from the `Enum`s:

```
public List<OptionDTO> getPetTypes() {

    List<OptionDTO> l = new ArrayList<>();

   for (PetType p: PetType.values​​())
       l.add (new OptionDTO(p.ordinal(), p.getType()));

   return l;
}
```

What I would like to implement is a private method that returns `List <OptionDTO>`. For example

```
public List<OptionDTO> getPetTypes() {
    return getList(PetType.values​​());
}
```

I am trying to use Generics but I have problems when I want to use the `getType()` method.

```
private<T extends Enum<T>> List<OptionDTO> getList(T[] list) {
    List<OptionDTO> l = new ArrayList<>();

    for(T t : list)
        l.add(new OptionDTO(t.ordinal(), t.getType()));

    return l;
}
```

My questions are:

1. Is there a way to implement Generics to access the `getType ()` method that is common to all the `Enums` I have?
2. Is this the recommended way to address the problem? Because I saw the use of interfaces there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do it like this:

```
interface HasType {
    String getType();
}
enum PetType implements HasType {
    ...
}
private <E extends Enum<E> & HasType> List<OptionDTO>(E[] values) {
    ...
}
```

The intersection type `Enum<E> & HasType` means that `E` has to be a subtype of both `Enum<E>` and `HasType`.

It's also the case that you could pass a `Class<E>` and use [`type.getEnumConstants()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getEnumConstants--) instead of passing the `values()` directly, if you ever needed to do that.

As a side note, it doesn't really make sense to give your `enum` setters. Enums are supposed to be immutable constants.

Comment: I'm just starting with `Enum`s and thought that I could skip the interface part because was a little confusing, but not now ;).
With immutable constants you mean that, once defined, I can not add another parameter, such as `PetType.add("WOLF")` or something like that?

Comment: Immutable just means you can't change the object's internal state. If an object has e.g. setters then it isn't immutable. For example, `String` is immutable and `StringBuilder` is mutable.